# javascript display/hide HTML element from radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 radio buttons in a group called "PersBus" and I'm trying to use them to select what content to show on a registration form. Value 1 = personal, Value 2 = Business, Value 3 = Both. So, for "1" I only want to show the form for Personal registration, and so on.  I'm brand new to js and

I did search quite a bit both here and on w3Schools to get this far, but no dice.

I can get the alerts to fire as expected, but I just can't seem to get the "grdPersonal" to show/hide.  I've also tried `.style.visibility` visible/hidden and no luck.

What am I missing? Is there a better way?

```js
function handleClick(PersBus) {
  var x = PersBus.value;
  var y = document.getElementById("grdPersonal");
  if (x === "1") {
    alert(x);
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    alert(x);
    document.getElementById("grdPersonal").style.display = 'none';
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="item1">
  <asp:RadioButton ID="radPersonal" runat="server" GroupName="PersBus" Checked="true" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="1" />
</div>
<div class="item2">
  <asp:RadioButton ID="radBusiness" runat="server" GroupName="PersBus" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="2" />
</div>
<div class="item3">
  <asp:RadioButton ID="radBoth" runat="server" GroupName="PersBus" onclick="handleClick(this);" value="3" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is not an ASP problem. I made you a snippet. Please REPLACE the ASP elements with RENDERED HTML in a [mcve] and add the grdPersonal element

Comment: You have `y = document.getElementById("grdPersonal");` plus `y.style.display = "none";`  and `document.getElementById("grdPersonal").style.display = 'none';` which will do the same

Comment: Yes, they are doing the same thing, I only left it this way to show what I had already tried i.e. var vs full text.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Use [the `hidden` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) instead of `style.display` which is an outdated and somewhat "incorrect" vestige from HTML prior to HTML 5.

Comment: I did not know that about hidden. I'll start using that from now on but it doesn't seem to be making any difference in this case.

Comment: document.getElementById("grdPersonal").setAttribute("hidden", true);   Still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you are hiding (display: none) the element in both cases.

```
function handleClick(PersBus) {
  var x = PersBus.value;
  var y = document.getElementById("grdPersonal");
  if (x === "1") {
    alert(x);
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    alert(x);
    y.style.display = 'block'; //change this
  }

}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend _against_ using `display` regardless of how the toggling is done -- this isn't about _displaying_ a document element, this is about whether the element is in fact at all _applicable_ or "enabled" in the document altogether. The correct approach is to use the `hidden` attribute instead. The good news (for you) is that it's trivial to re-factor code that uses `style.display` into one that uses `hidden`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I can't even get it to display 'none'... the element is displayed by default on load.  I was just trying different syntax to see if I could get it to display 'none' knowing that if I could make that work, it would probably all work.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ArmenMichaeli why wouldn't you use display none? display hidden still takes up space, so it "destroys" the layout of the page... (unless you change css to `.hidden{width:0;height:0;}`

Comment: @Kevin I would advise you to use console log to check the values (x), and to see where it stops working / is no longer working as you intended.

Comment: @DoomBot I didn't say don't use `display: none`, I said don't use `display` at all (in these cases). `display` communicates _displaying_ of an element, which isn't entirely correct in this case -- you want to "disable" the element from participating in the form submission and visual layout. That's what [the `hidden` _attribute_](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#attr-hidden) is for. This is about _semantics_, not what works -- rest assured your element will be "hidden" using either, for varying definition of "hidden". HTML is about semantics, presentation is a CSS thing.

Comment: @DoomBot I'm embarrased to say that I hadn't even thought to use console.log  It is helping me narrow the issue but its problem is "cannot read properties of null (reading 'setattribute')" which it shouldn't be having based on my reading so far. The element ID is correct and the script runs after the element is created in the DOM so now I'm stumped again.

Comment: Kevin I don't actually know what the problem is, but I'm assuming that you're calling the function before the element is created (that's the first thing that comes to mind, as you're saying that the error is "cannot read properties of null"). @ArmenMichaeli I do kind of agree with the what you're saying. On the other hand, the code has to work first, then you can change it, so it makes more sense. The bottom line is, it doesn't matter if it makes sense (to anyone else then yourself) as long as it works (and you're working alone)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I finally figured it out.  My "grdPersonal" element had a `runat="server"` attribute that caused it to call the function before the element was created, which it why I was getting the "cannot read properties of null"

Thanks everyone for the help. Always learning.